# windows application

Tags: c#

Am doing one project in C# windows application with MVC pattern. In that i need to access the controls from client Form to ClientStatus Form any ideas

Comment: @closers and downvoters: You could at least leave a comment.

Comment: @Henk, "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here". It sounds very project-specific.

Comment: @Tim, I know but it's obvious the OP is new here, so at least tell him what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your forms fall under the V (view) part of MVC; they only need to present data to the user and provide means for interaction. They don't need to know about what other forms are doing because that is handled in the controller...

Logic to react to user interaction should be contained in the C (controller) part. So in your example the controller will respond to user input on one form to update the state of the other form.

In basic terms your controller should instantiate the forms, react to events on the interactive form, and call methods or modify properties on the other form to update it. The method you use to achieve this depends on the technology you are using; if you are using WinForms then use [events and delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720047(v=VS.71).aspx). If you are using WPF then you should look into [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually using MVC your Forms shouldn't need each other controls. Your forms shouldn't even know each other.

Please explain your situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you post no code explaining your implementation of MVC in WinForms, I'm not sure how you're actually instantiating and showing the Forms. I'll assume that you're still calling constructors somewhere in your own code though.

Pass a reference to the Client Form when the ClientStatus form is created (and create a constructor on the ClientStatus form to accept the Client Form as a parameter):

```
public class ClientForm : Form
{
    public ClientForm() { }
}

public class ClientStatusForm : Form
{
    ClientForm _parent;

    public ClientStatusForm(ClientForm parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }
}
```